SwiftUi navigate from alert
I started with swiftui recently and im just trying things and i cant seem to find a solution but i need to navigate to another screen but only after choosing yes in an alert that shows up.
Is it even possible in swiftui to navigate from an alert to another screen ?
I tried using navigationView (even tho is deprecated), and using navigationStack, all the different ways to use the navigationlink and nothing worked.

I'm sure have done something already. Please provide a minimal example

Try using a NavigationStack with a path + .navigationDestination. Then just append the target to the path in the alert.

Yes there is a way using NavigationStack. Here is some sample code that does what you are trying to achieve.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingNextDestination: Bool = false
    @State private var isShowingAlert: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Button("Show Alert") {
                    isShowingAlert.toggle()
                }
            }
            .alert("Show next screen", isPresented: $isShowingAlert) {
                Button("Yes") {
                    isShowingNextDestination = true
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isShowingNextDestination) {
                Color.red
            }
        }
    }
}

Happy coding
